# How do I connect to a network using Substrate Connect?

Tags: substrate-connect, browser-extension

I have the Substrate Connect light client [browser extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/substrate-connect-extensi/khccbhhbocaaklceanjginbdheafklai) installed but there are no networks listed in the options.

Click into the `Options` in the extension:

[image: Browser extension]

Clicking `Networks` does nothing:

[image: Browser extension settings page]

How do I connect to a substrate-based network using this extension?

The [docs](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate-connect/#extension) don't give many hints. I have **bolded** part of the below.

> For in-browser use, Substrate Connect provides a Browser Extension
> built upon the @substrate/light node module that is running the
> selected light clients **inside the extension** so that the end-user
> doesn't need to fire up a light node in every browser tab. This will
> also allow the light-node to keep syncing as long as the browser
> window stays open.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apps that are built with substrate connect compatibility will detect whether the user has the extension and use it, or create the WASM light client in-page for them.

https://paritytech.github.io/substrate-connect/

For instance, Polkadot, Kusama and Westend can be accessed through Substrate Connect. After opening https://polkadot.js.org/apps/#/explorer you have an option to switch to light client

[image]

If the connection is successful, you should see it under the networks tab

[image]

Comment: Does this mean the chain is only syncing in the extension if an app is connected?

Comment: @forgetso not really. While extension is running the well known networks (Polkadot, kusama, rococo and westend) are syncing in the background and the latest state is saved in the localstorage. This way when an app is connected will start syncing from that latest state, which makes the sync period smaller.